# How do I sum the y-values of an 2D array based on the corresponding x-value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array where `x` is the date, and `y` is the value. I want to sum the values for each date.

```
0: {x: "8/20", y: 10}
1: {x: "8/19", y: 80}
2: {x: "8/18", y: 10}
3: {x: "8/18", y: 10}
4: {x: "8/18", y: 20}
...
19: {x: "8/13", y: 10}
20: {x: "8/13", y: 50}
21: {x: "8/13", y: -10}
22: {x: "8/13", y: 30}
23: {x: "8/13", y: 40}
24: {x: "8/13", y: 10}
```

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Expected result:

```
0: {date: "8/20", sum: 10}
1: {date: "8/19", sum: 80}
2: {date: "8/18", sum: 30}
...
6: {date: "8/13", sum: 130}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to sum arrays using ECMASCRIPT 6 Generator/Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229853/what-is-the-best-way-to-sum-arrays-using-ecmascript-6-generator-functions)

Comment: You need to improve your question. See here how can you do it [ask]

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @hev1, added expected result.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter, I don't think that works since I'm dealing with 2D arrays

Comment: @maioman, that basically gives me something like: `8/13: "8/13", 8/17: "8/17", 8/18: "8/18", 8/20: "8/20"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to sum elements with the same date.

```
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,{x,y})=>{
     acc[x] = acc[x] || {date: x, sum: 0};
     acc[x].sum += y;
     return acc;
}, {}));
```